# how to catch timeout exception in async WSRequest in Play framework 2.x?

Tags: asynchronous, playframework, playframework-2.0, timeout

I am trying to catch TimeoutException in a delegate in Play framework 2.1.x, my code looks like:

```
WSRequestHolder request = WS.url(url).setAuth(username,password);
Promise<WS.Response> response = request.get();
    response.onRedeem(new Callback<WS.Response>(){
    public void invoke(WS.Response response) {
        int status = response.getStatus();
        Logger.info("Sending result");
        Logger.info(response.getBody());
    }
});
```

In Play the default timeout value is 120000ms and I want to catch that timeout exception. I tried using try-catch block but it does not seem to work. Anyone can help? Should I use a timer instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can handle [TimeoutException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeoutException.html) exception with one of the following methods of [Promise](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.1/api/java/play/libs/F.Promise.html): `onFailure`, `recover` or `recoverWith`.